# why is a variable changing when passed through my "get chart" function in javascript. using google charts api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a variable that is being altered or stored incorrectly when I call a function to get a chart from a database (directed through a php file). All of the data from the php side is cleaned and corrected, but the markers on the eastern half of the map always have an error, becauase the correct site_id isn't being passed. When the site_id is passed a chart pops up next to the marker and it works fine. Get chart is only called when a "chart" button is clicked in the info window. The info window pops up when a marker is clicked.

I have tried: declaring site_id inside the createmarkers function, passing sitelist[i][1] instead or site_id inside getchart, placing the getchart function before the createmarkers function.

When I put in the autochart web address with the site_id for the markers that are problematic, a perfect chart pops up.

Correct site_id: 06903990
what the console logs after getchart is called 1450976

**My create markers function**

```
var site_id;
function createmarkers(sitelist) {
  var marker;
  var markericon;
 const image = "correctwebaddress/river2.png";
 for (var i = 0; i < sitelist.length; i++) {
    markercount++;
    point = {lat: sitelist[i][4], lng: sitelist[i][5]};
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: point,
      icon: image,
      title: "Site ID: " + sitelist[i][1] + " Name: " + sitelist[i][2],
      map: map
    });
    site_id=sitelist[i][1];
    console.log(site_id);
   info = "<b>Site ID:</b> " + sitelist[i][1] + "<BR><b>Name:</b> " + sitelist[i][2] +"<button  onclick='getchart("+ site_id+")'>Chart</button>"; ;
    marker.info = info;
 marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infobox.setContent(this.info);
     infobox.open(map, this);
     console.log(site_id);
      });
   allmarkers.push(marker)
  }
}
```

**My getChart function**

```
 function getchart(site_id) {
  console.log('get chart called');
  console.log(site_id);                        // this is where the site_id is different
  let url = "correcturl/autochart.php?site_id=0" + site_id;
  console.log(url);
  document.getElementById("chart").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = "<iframe src='correctwebaddress/autochart.php?site_id=0" + site_id+"'  frameborder='0' width='595' height='295' scrolling='no'></iframe>";
 }
```

Comment: How specifically is the value "different"?  It looks like `getChart` is called directly from the HTML markup and explicitly passes a value to the function.  When you examine the DOM in your browser's debugging tools to see that markup (the "Chart" button), what is that value?  Does it differ from what's being logged in the console within the function?  I suspect this needs a little more debugging on your part.